# Transition without moving background (CSS and HTML)

Tags: html, css, hover, transition

I'm still new in coding, so you'll see some unnecessary codes in the css..
My problem is, I want to make the background stays/static when hovered, I believe my hover style is called "slide".. But when I hover on, the background did hover too. So, I need a help on how to make the background static when hovered.

p/s: please remain the margin for avpb :)

**CSS:**

```
#avpb {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
width: 160px; 
height: 220px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
padding: 19.5px;
margin-top: -10px;
margin-left: 555px;
position: absolute;
}

#avp {
position: absolute;
width: 160px;
height: 220px;
}

#avp img {
position: absolute;
z-index: 0;
}

.overlay {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition:all .3s ease-out;
-moz-transition:all .3s ease-out;
-ms-transition:all .3s ease-out;
-o-transition:all .3s ease-out;
transition:all .3s ease-out;
}

#avp:hover > .overlay {
opacity: 1;
width: 160px;
height: 220px 
height:auto;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
-webkit-transform:translate(0px,10px);
-moz-transform:translate(0px,10px);
-ms-transform:translate(0px,10px);
-o-transform:translate(0px,10px);
transform:translate(0px,10px);
}

.button {
width: 160px;
height: 220px;
position: absolute;
}

.button a {
font-family: Lato;
font-size: 10px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
width: 80px;
height: 25px;
line-height: 25px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
border: 1px solid #000000;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 5px;
color: #ffffff !important;
display: block;
transition: 0.5s ease; 
-webkit-transition: 0.5s ease; 
-o-transition: 0.5s ease; 
-ms-transition: 0.5s ease; 
}

.button a:hover {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
border: 1px solid #4cd1db;
color: #4cd1db !important;
text-decoration: none;
letter-spacing: 2px;
transition: 0.5s ease; 
-webkit-transition: 0.5s ease; 
-o-transition: 0.5s ease; 
-ms-transition: 0.5s ease; 
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="avpb">
<div id="avp">
<img src="http://www.imvu.com/catalog/web_av_pic.php?u=87116145">
<div class="overlay">
<div class="button">
<br>
<br>
<a href="http://www.imvu.com/catalog/web_add_contact.phpcontact=applesunsweets">add</a>
<br>
<a href="javascript:IMVU.messagePopupShow({force_recipient_id:87116145})">message</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwxs0uh3/86/)

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive?  I can't understand what exactly you want.

Comment: @crazypaste Sorry.. So my problem here, how to make the background in `#avp:hover > .overlay` static as I hover on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just let the **.button** transform then. I added some styles to your css file, hard to explain, just try and compare it with your original code :).

```css
#avpb {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 160px;
  height: 220px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 19.5px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: 555px;
  position: absolute;
}

#avp {
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px;
  height: 220px;
}

#avp img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
.button{
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

#avp:hover>.overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 160px;
  height: 220px height:auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
#avp:hover>.overlay>.button {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 160px;
  height: 220px height:auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 10px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0px, 10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 10px);
  -o-transform: translate(0px, 10px);
  transform: translate(0px, 10px);
}

.button {
  width: 160px;
  height: 220px;
  position: absolute;
}

.button a {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.button a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border: 1px solid #4cd1db;
  color: #4cd1db !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="avpb">
  <div id="avp">
    <img src="http://www.imvu.com/catalog/web_av_pic.php?u=87116145">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="button">
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="http://www.imvu.com/catalog/web_add_contact.phpcontact=applesunsweets">add</a>
        <br>
        <a href="javascript:IMVU.messagePopupShow({force_recipient_id:87116145})">message</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I think I confused people here.. I wanted the buttons to move, but not the background. Yes.

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what I wanted! Thank you!! :D but something concern me here that why didn't you merged the `.button` with the transition style into the `.button` with the width, height and position style? @blackmiaool

Comment: @AllyZulfadhli  Because I didn't read all your code, just added some vital code to make it work. You can merge it yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are transforming/translating the div to be 10 pixels down:

```
  -webkit-transform:translate(0px,10px);
  -moz-transform:translate(0px,10px);
  -ms-transform:translate(0px,10px);
  -o-transform:translate(0px,10px);
  transform:translate(0px,10px);
```

Delete these and it should work fine.